# On output, wrap table with long columns into multiple columns using same headers

Tags: r, formatting

I'd like to take a long table, with two columns of data that are NOT long format data, and make it into a wide table with the same data, so its more readable, e.g.

```
tb <- data.frame(Lets = letters, Nums = seq(1:26))
tb
```

which outputs something like this:

```
   Lets Nums
1     a    1  
2     b    2  
..  
25    y   25  
26    z   26
```

Instead how best to output the table, or reformat it for output, to look something like this:

```
   Lets Nums     Lets  Nums       Lets  Nums        Lets  Nums  etc. 
1     a    1   6    f     6    11    k    11    16     p    16  etc.
2     b    2   7    g     7    12    l    12    etc.
3     c    3   8    h     8    etc
4     d    4   9    i     9
5     e    5  10    j    10
```

Have  tried fiddling with kable, reshape and pivot_wider but they're all setup for converting from long FORMAT data to wide FORMAT data. Not just presenting a table in a more readable format on a screen or page. Using split, got some of the way there, but not for human-friendly output:

```
kable(split(tb, f = (row(tb) %% 5)), caption = "this didn't work", digits = 1)
```

Table: this didn't work

|  | Lets | Nums |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | e | 5 |
| 10 | j | 10 |
| 15 | o | 15 |
| 20 | t | 20 |
| 25 | y | 25 |

|   |Lets | Nums|
|:--|:----|----:|
|1  |a    |    1|
|6  |f    |    6|
|11 |k    |   11|
etc.

All suggestions gratefully received. Have to admit that after 90 minutes of fiddling and searching, I just gave in and did it in Excel instead in about 3 minutes...